# How to create a function in Excel to validate cells using RegExs

Tags: regex, excel, vba, user-defined-functions, worksheet-function

I have a long spreadsheet with tariff codes that I need to validate and I would like to create a function with RegEx to do it automatically (this is a daily task that I will have to do for the following months and I would like to automatize)

For example in Column A, I have the following data:

CODE
1000.00.00
1000.10.00
1020.12.99
...

But some times, the codes are mispelled like (1020..23.99 or 1020.23.124), and I would like to make a validation in column B with a function like this in each cell:

```
=isvalid_function(A2,"^\d{3,4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}$")
```

..and get TRUE or FALSE as result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the reference to **Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions** to Excel, then you can use Regex, see [this link](http://excel.aircoolednut.com/documents/Using%20regular%20expressions.doc) for some more detail.  Then you'd create a UDF called *isvalid_function* that would implement that.

Comment: I how the UDF should be? I dont know VBA

Comment: @sword, You have to create a UDF in VBA, it's not hard to do and there are lots of pages you can google to explain it.  [Here's](http://www.exceltip.com/st/Writing_Your_First_VBA_Function_in_Excel/631.html) one page that goes over some basics, and [another](http://www.tmehta.com/regexp/) covers some Regex functions specifically.